# Variable from controller not send to view in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am using HMVC with CodeIgniter.

I have this in my testmodule controller:

```
public function index()
{ 
     $this->view_data['main_content'] = 'frontpage';
     $this->load->view('template', $this->view_data);
}
```

And this in my view template.php of that controller that is loaded by this controller:

```
    <?php 

      $this->load->view('includes/header');

      $this->load->view($main_content);

      $this->load->view('includes/footer'); 

    ?>
```

but, when I var_dump($main_content) in the view and die() it shows **null** instead of **frontpage**

How, come? I don't get it at all.

Comment: I don't thing there is anything wrong with this code. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: I have solved it by chnging $this->view_data to $view_data and it suddenly works. However, I have no idea why. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `$this->view_data` you have to declare `$view_data` as a [property](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) first (at the top of your controller):

```
class TestModule extends CI_Controller
{
  public $view_data = array();

  public function index()
  {
    // Now you can use $this->view_data in this function:
    $this->view_data['main_content'] = 'frontpage';
    $this->load->view('template', $this->view_data);
  }
}
```